# Hide the taskbar in a win32 application

Tags: c++, winapi, desktop-application

I'm trying to hide the taskbar in a win32 application.
However, in the case of multiple monitors, the taskbar of the primary monitor is hidden, but the taskbar of the other monitor remains.
How can I solve this?
The code I implemented is below.

```
void ShowTaskbar(bool bShow)
{
    static HWND hShellWnd = ::FindWindow(_T("Shell_TrayWnd"), NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, bShow ? SW_SHOW : SW_HIDE);
}
```

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Frequently, when people ask how to hide the taskbar, they do not actually want to hide the taskbar. What problem are you ultimately trying to solve?

Comment: Taskbars on multiple monitors use the `Shell_SecondaryTrayWnd` class. Use `EnumWindows()` to find them.

Comment: Do not run around hiding other people's windows. That gets state out of sync and tends to create further problems that are hard to diagnose  (For example, what if your app crashes before it can unhide the taskbar? What if the taskbar tries to unhide itself?) Just create a fullscreen window and the taskbar will auto-hide.

Comment: IInspectable, Thanks for your reply. I want to hide the taskbar while the program is running and show the taskbar again when the program closes.
However, if multiple monitors are installed, the taskbar is hidden only on the primary screen and remains on the other screens. I'm trying to fix this.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks for your answer. I did what you said and then it works.
Can you post the answer so I can adopt it?

Comment: @edwar You should heed the advice from Raymond, bearing in mind that he is a long time developer of Windows

Comment: Ok, round two then: Why do you want to hide the taskbar?

Comment: Hiding the taskbar is a request of my client and you can find out about my project by following the link below.     
 https://www.dropbox.com/s/rudg3nszh1tj9ul/DSC_0585.MOV?dl=0

Comment: Dude... this is getting tedious. So then, why does your client want to hide the taskbar? And please, don't come back with something like *"because their client requested that"*.

Comment: I'm starting to get annoyed too. Why are you trying to tackle me without answering my question? Did you watch the video? Did you see the Taskbar there? You have absolutely no reason to doubt me.

Comment: Err, no, I don't click random links. If you cannot explain what problem you need solved, in words, you're on your own. Good luck.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks for your answer! Helped me solve a problem relating to determining the workarea of secondary monitors.